# White background on Preference for Tablets

Tags: android, background, preferenceactivity, android-theme

I am setting a background for my preference activity, so I wrote a style in styles.xml

```
<style 
   name="PreferencesTheme" 
   parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

and in the activity,

```
  <activity
          android:name="com.phonelight.realparrot.MainActivity"
          android:label="Real Parrot"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>

  </activity>
```

I run this on the emulator for two devices. The first one is a mobile phone, the second is a Tablet.
[image: mobile phone]
[image: Tablet]

Why the background image does not appear on the Tablet. There is only a small margin. I run it on a real Tablet and the whole screen is white too.

Comment: What API version for both?

Comment: Mobile phone is Android 2.2;  Tablet is Android 3.0

Comment: Do you think setting the background in a theme does not work for preference Activity on Tablets. Maybe I should set the background for the preference Activity in the java code, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to be using a different theme. I'm not sure why the difference between the two exactly, but I suspect slight differences in API.

```
<style 
   name="PreferencesTheme" 
   parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It does not work. I solve the problem by adding in the java code:  preference.setBackgroundResource(R.xml.background);      I appreciate your help though.

Comment: If you could post an answer to your question, it would help people who stumble upon the same issue later, and would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by adding in the Preference Activity

```
preference.setBackgroundResource(R.xml.background);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled across this problem for tablets but yasserbn's answer did not help me, namely there is no indication of what...

```
preference.setBackgroundResource(R.xml.background);
```

...is being called on.

On Android large screens, PreferenceActivity restarts itself to show the preferences in a fragment. The issue arises because we cannot change the background of this fragment container as its layout id, com.android.internal.R.id.prefs_frame, is private.

A workaround for this is to recursively clear the backgrounds for all child views, since we can always get ahold of the root view:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ThemeManager.setTheme(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    clearBackground(findViewById(android.R.id.content));

    // other stuff...
}

private void clearBackground(View view) {
    view.setBackgroundResource(0);
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
            clearBackground(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
    }
}
```

It's not perfectly, namely if any of your preferences make use of a custom views with backgrounds, though that is unlikely anyways.